# Integral $\int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\,e^{i \theta+a e^{i \theta} + b e^{-i \theta}}$ in terms of Bessel Function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Is it possible to find

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\,e^{i \theta+a e^{i \theta} + b e^{-i \theta}}$$

in terms of Bessel functions?

Comment: $2\pi\sqrt{b/a}I_1(2\sqrt{ab})$.

Comment: I can't see this. Could you expand?

Comment: OK now I do! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll give the answer for the more general integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta n}\mathrm{e}^{a\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}+b\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \theta}}.$$
We begin by expanding the second exponential in the integral as a power series:
$$\mathrm{e}^{a\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}+b\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \theta}}=\sum_{\mu,\nu\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{\mu!\nu!}a^\mu b^\nu\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta(\mu-\nu)},$$
where we are allowed to start at negative infinity for both indices, since $1/n!$ is zero for all natural numbers $n<0$. By use of the Cauchy product formula, we find for the double sum
$$\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^\mu\frac{a^\mu b^{\mu-\nu}}{\mu!(\mu-\nu)!}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta\nu}\right).$$
Inserting this back into the original integral, we get from the orthogonality of the complex exponential:
$$\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^\mu\frac{a^\mu b^{\mu-\nu}}{\mu!(\mu-\nu)!}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta n}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta\nu}=\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^\mu\frac{a^\mu b^{\mu-\nu}}{\mu!(\mu-\nu)!}\delta_{\nu,-n},$$
which allows us to simplify the sum as
$$\sum_{\mu=0}^\infty\frac{a^\mu b^{\mu+n}}{\mu!(\mu+n)!}.$$
From there, its just a matter of identifying the modified Bessel function of the first kind:
$$\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{\mu=0}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{ab})^{2\mu+n}}{\mu!(\mu+n)!}=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}I_n(2\sqrt{ab}).$$
Therefore, we have for the original expression
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta n}\mathrm{e}^{a\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}+b\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \theta}}=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}I_n(2\sqrt{ab})}$$
Your desired integral is the case $n=1$ as provided by @metamorphy.